# Sets, subsets and set notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've got a few queries about sets. Just getting confused on these concepts:

**First question:**

$R = \{ X \in A : X \notin X \}$

What does $X$ actually represent and why are we using it? I am guessing $X$ is a place holder for the elements of $A$ $( X \in A)$. But why are we using $X$ in $( X \notin X)$, can't we just write $R \notin R$ instead? Doesn't it have the same meaning?

**Second question:**

$\{1\} \subseteq \{1,2,3\}$, $\{1\}$ is a subset of $\{1,2,3\}$

but

Why is $\bigl\{\{1,2\}\bigr\} \not\subset \bigl\{\{1,2,3\}\bigr\}$. $\bigl\{\{1,2\}\bigr\}$ does contain some elements from $\bigl\{\{1,2,3\}\bigr\}$, so why is it not a subset?

**Third question:**

$1 \in \{1,2,3\}$, $1$ is a member of the set $\{1,2,3\}$

but

Why is $\{2\} \notin \{1,2,3\}$, Isn't $\{2\}$ a member of $\{1,2,3\}$, so why is it not a member?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Q1 : Yes, $~X~$ is just a placeholder, as you described.  By using $~X~$ a second time, you are specifying that a specific element is in $~A~$ but is not in the 2nd set.  Here, the second set should be something like $~B,~$ as in $~X \not\in B.~$  Also using $~X~$ as a reference to the second set is **bad**; it constitutes overloading the symbol $~X.$ ...see next comment

Comment: For the other questions, it is important to distinguish between (for example) $~M = \{ ~1 ~\},~$ and $~N = \{ ~\{1\} ~\}.~$  $~M~$ is a set with only one element, which is the element $~1.~$  $~N~$ is also a set with only one element.  However, the element in $~N,~$ is itself a set.  In fact, the set $~M~$ is itself an element of the set $~N.$

Comment: Wouldn't it be far better in the first example to use small letters for elements, such as $x\in A$?

Comment: You're right, sorry I'm not used to writing on here.

Comment: @user2661923 If M = { 1 } is a set by itself, then why isn't it a member of {1,2,3}? im still confused on this point.

Comment: The set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is like a box containing an apple, and orange and a banana. The set $\{\{1\}, 2, 3\}$ is then a box containing an orange, a banana, and *another box* with an apple in it. If I ask you whether the first box contains "a box with an apple in it", the answer is no - it only contains the apple itself.

Comment: See [The difference between ∈ and ⊂](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461870/the-difference-between-%e2%88%88-and-%e2%8a%82)

Comment: Do not "flatten" the sets in your mind.  $1 \neq \{1\}$.  Do not conflate the meaning of *is an element of* and *is a subset of* with one another.  $\{\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{2},\color{green}{3}\}$ has the red element $\color{red}{1}$ as an element but does not have the purple $\color{purple}{\{1\}}$ *which includes the braces as an unignorable part of the object* as an element.